# Ubuntu Server 14.10 same Hostname in- and outside

Tags: server, 14.10, hostname

So, my router doesn't support loopback, so I have to always have two bookmarks to access my server, one for local and one for external.

While this is not really a problem, its more of a problem for plugins and programms, where you have to change the settings everytime you want to access from either internal or external. And unfortunately not all of the programms support multiple profiles to change it without edditing the settings everytime.

So, my question is if it's possible to have the same hostname on the inside. Let's say my DNS on the outside is myserver.homelinux.org. The server is called "server" so I can only access the server from the inside via the URl server.local.

I've tried to change it to myserver.homelinux.org and stuff like that. I changed the shortname to myserver and the FQDN full Hostname to myserver.homelinux.org but it didn't work. The server was not accessible via myserver.homelinux.org from the inside, but via myserver.local. I changed it with

```
sudo hostname myserver
```

and

```
sudo hostname -f myserver.homelinux.org
```

and of course eddited /etc/hosts file. Still, nothing

So, what did I do wrong? Is it even possible? What do I have to do, to access it local and external with the same address?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu `sudo vim /etc/hostname` put the FQDN. Then feel free to conform your `/etc/hosts`. Example below. Feel free to add your `hostname.local` naming scheme.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1   hostname.yourdomain.tld hostname
YourIP      hostname.yourdomain.tld hostname
```

If you want your remote server to be reachable over the internet via its FQDN, then you need to create the relevant DNS records. Hint from here https://github.com/DigitalOcean-User-Projects/Articles-and-Tutorials/blob/master/set_hostname_fqdn_on_ubuntu_centos.md